# Clicking on this button using IMacros

Tags: jquery, html, imacros

I am trying to make an IMacros code click this button on a web page, however it is not working, as it can find the button but won't actually click on it, I am using this code:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=a ATTR=TXT:Joined
```

and the HTML of the button is:

```
<a id="order_created_at" class="active" href="#top" onmousedown="unfollow.changeSortOrder('created_at', 'ASC');return false;">Joined <i class="icon-caret-down"></i></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is like this:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=ID:"order_created_at"
URL GOTO=javascript:{window.document.getElementById("order_created_at").onmousedown();undefined;}
```